# What does this error mean?? Arduino Due loop warning

Tags: arduino-due, rgb-led

I am getting this error on compilation of the code given further below;

> warning: iteration 3u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
>
> leds[XY (x, y)].r = redarray[x][y];
> note: containing loop
> for(uint8_t x=0; x < MatrixWidth; x++){

Code:

```
 // the header files for the RGB data

#include <FastLED.h>
#include "redarray.h"   
#include "greenarray.h"   //g data header file (hex or dec)
#include "bluearray.h"   //b data header file (hex or dec)*/

 //matrix parameters

#define MatrixWidth 36 //columns (x)
#define MatrixHeight 1 //rows (y)
#define numled (MatrixWidth * MatrixHeight)

//pin details

#define datapin 7

#define clockpin 8

CRGB leds[MatrixWidth * MatrixHeight];

const bool  MatrixSerpentineLayout = true;

void setup() {

   FastLED.addLeds<APA102, datapin, clockpin>(leds,numled);
   FastLED.clear();
         }

void loop() {    
   for(uint8_t y=0 ; y<1 ; y++){
     for(uint8_t x=0; x < MatrixWidth; x++){ 
         leds[XY (x, y)].r = redarray[x][y];
         leds[XY (x, y)].g = 0;
         leds[XY (x, y)].b = 0;

         FastLED.show(); 
         delay(50);         
     }
   }   
 }

  uint16_t XY( uint8_t x, uint8_t y)  
  {
      uint16_t i;

      if( MatrixSerpentineLayout == true) {
          if( y & 0x01) {
          // Odd rows run backwards
          uint8_t reverseX = (MatrixWidth - 1) - x;
          i = (y * MatrixWidth) + reverseX;
    } else {
         // Even rows run forwards
         i = (y * MatrixWidth) + x;
    }
}  
   return i;
}
```

The following is redarray header -

//RED
const byte redarray[3][36] PROGMEM = {
{0x00,  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

};

How to remove this warning. The redarray is not being read properly by arduino. THe above code should make the 36 LEDs turn off (black) as per the header file. They are randomly lit red... I am totally perplexed!

Plz help if somebody can.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatrixWidth` is 36. `redarray[]` has 3 elements. The compiler has detected that your code will likely blow up on the 4th go through the loop. Make sure your code is accessing the dimensions correctly.

Comment: (great name btw! :P) ...I referred to this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm and it says that the brackets around indvidual elements are optional. So, by that , my redarray is a 3 row 36 column array. Which one is correct? Any could you please tell how to access the dimensions correctly. I am stuck on this since quite a long time. the leds[XY(x,y)]= redarray[x][y] ....is this accessing of array and allocating to leds correct???? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean which is correct? Your first dimension only has a fixed 3 elements. Attempting to access beyond that is a bug.

Comment: I declared my redarray as { {r,r,r,r...36 elements}, {e,e,e,e,e...36 elements}, {t,t,t,t,...36 elements} }; in three rows...isn't that a 3*36 matrix? On the link, it is defined like this only....each row within {} ?? Thats my confusion....

Comment: You're too mired in trivialities. **Your first dimension has three elements. If you try to access it with a value greater than 2 then your code may blow up.**

Comment: Varquez-Abrams ..i do understand the point you are trying to put across, however, I cannot spot the mistake still.. Or what correction i need to make..Sorry brother... Would have to think more about it... I asked this yesterday something like this too, did the changes but now a new error.will have to see... Thanks though...

Comment: What values can `x` take on?

Comment: So, here i what I understand or see - y takes only one value 0 and that is the first row of the matrix. X goes from 0-35 (36 LEDs) and thus I am calling out the entire first row of the matrix (which itself is one row only). redarray is 3*36. based on my understanding that signifies 3 rows with each row having 36 elements(rows are explicitly defined). And thus I am mapping one-to-one with the leds and redarray. But in reality that aint happening. I am wrong I know..trying to figure out sir

Comment: The problem you're having is that you're thinking of it in "rows" and "columns", and that is hopelessly confusing you. Think in dimensions and their order instead.

Comment: I completely understand the left hand side of the line leds[XY(x,y)] but i am confused ( and u r right abt the rows and columns thing.. M lost there only) about the redarray part. How does Arduino "move" through this array with the given for loop? The ans to this depends on how does one define "elements" in a 2D array? A one D array is linear ( one dim) so a [m][n] array is a 1D array of length m replicated n times in the other dimension. I think i get what u r saying.. But then how do you define a 3*36 array if my style of decl is wrong? Thanks

Comment: You've already defined the 3*36 array. But you're treating it like a 36*3 array.

Comment: After thinking about your last comment, I finally managed to see the mistake - on RHS i.e. redarray[x][y] ..In place of this it should be redarray[y][x] I got the correct pattern. And I also realised that where I was getting lost, leds[XY(x,y)] employs the coordinate system concept as per FastLED. I was getting confused between this coordinates and dimensions of array. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much and more than that..thanks for not telling me directly the mistake..but through hints ;) :) ..I learnt something. I hope I am correct now. :P :)